# How do we handle the symmetry condition in nCob and TQFTs?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory, cobordism, symmetric-monoidal-categories

A $(n+1)$-topological quantum field theory $\mathcal{T}$ is a rigid symmetric monoidal functor from the category **$(n+1)$-Cob** of $n$-manifolds and $(n+1)$-cobordisms to **FdVect**.
My question is about the symmetric monoidal structure of **$(n+1)$-Cob** and how it plays well with functoriality:

We consider our manifolds abstractly (as opposed to being embedded in some ambient space). The monoidal structure in **$(n+1)$-Cob** is given by disjoint union, thus
$$M\otimes N = M \sqcup N$$
for manifolds $M,N$, and likewise for cobordisms. But since our manifolds are just abstract, surely this is exactly the same object as
$$N\otimes M=N\sqcup M.$$
But when we pass to **FdVect** our functor gives
$$ \mathcal{T}(M\otimes N)=\mathcal{T}M \otimes \mathcal{T}N $$
while
$$ \mathcal{T}(N\otimes M) = \mathcal{T}N \otimes \mathcal{T}M $$
which are certainly isomorphic but distinct objects.

So clearly something is broken in my understanding of this, but what?
Do we somehow distinguish between $M\otimes N$ and $N\otimes M$ in **$(n+1)$-Cob**?
If so, how, given that these are just abstract manifolds?

Comment: You should think about what, really, you mean by the collection of symbols $M \sqcup N$. If you want this construction to give you an actual abstract manifold, it should also give you an actual abstract underlying set: which set is it?

Comment: So one way of defining the disjoint union $M\sqcup N$ is to simply take the set of points of $M$ and $N$ separately, "label" each point (with a subscript say) in order to distinguish which set it came from, and then take the ordinary set union. But this doesn't distinguish $M\sqcup N$ and $N \sqcup M$.

Comment: Another definition of disjoint union I've heard is that $M\sqcup N = M\times \{0\} \cup N\times \{1\}$, under this definition $M\sqcup N$ indeed is different from $N\sqcup M$, is this what you're alluding to?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean: there are then canonical isomorphisms $M \sqcup N \to N \sqcup M$, which are not the identity maps, and which give the cobordism category a symmetric monoidal structure.

Comment: I see. So in taking disjoint unions one can choose to index the constituent sets in such a way as to either keep track of, or forget, their ordering (i.e. index by a set's "name" versus its ordinality). It's interesting how I find the first option more intuitive ("they're just sets, ordering in their $\sqcup$ shouldn't matter!") but in this case it's unhelpful to think about it that way.

Comment: Not quite, labelling by the set's "name" is not a good idea: what would $M \sqcup M$ be in that case?

Comment: Well, by "name" I just mean their index in some indexing set $\mathcal{I}$, but where $\mathcal{I}$ is not ordered. So I suppose we'd index the "left" $M$ by $i$ say, the "right" $M$ by $j$, and just have $M\sqcup M = M \times \{i,j\}$. But I think this is starting to become more set-theoretic (possibly a new question) than this current question calls for, maybe we can start a discussion or a new question. Thanks very much @Oscar!

Comment: Any symmetric tensor category can be strictified, so there's certainly some version of the bordism category where $M \sqcup N = N \sqcup M$.  Scrictification is not a very natural thing to do though, and Oscar's right that with standard definitions $M \sqcup N \neq N \sqcup M$.

Comment: While it is possible to arrange for $M \amalg N = N \amalg M$ as objects, it is not in general possible to make the "swap" isomorphism $M \amalg N \to N \amalg M$ equal to the identity morphism. So there's really no point in forcing $M \amalg N = N \amalg M$ anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Oscar has explained in comments, with the most common definitions it's just not true that $M \sqcup N$ is exactly the same as $N \sqcup M$.  But even if you were working with some version of the category of sets where they were equal, this wouldn't be a problem because tensor functors don't have to be strict.  In other words, you don't know that $\mathscr{F}(M \sqcup N) = \mathscr{F}(M)\otimes \mathscr{F}(N)$, but instead only that you have isomorphisms $\mathscr{F}(M \sqcup N) \cong \mathscr{F}(M)\otimes \mathscr{F}(N)$ satisfying the natural coherence conditions.  In particular, $\mathscr{F}(M \sqcup N) = \mathscr{F}(N \sqcup M)$ does not imply that $\mathscr{F}(M)\otimes \mathscr{F}(N) = \mathscr{F}(N)\otimes \mathscr{F}(M)$, but only that the latter are isomorphic in a coherent way.